# How to find missing Number along with the numbers present in table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch data for one of my clients, but there are missing tokens in his data. I tried the below query for fetching the missing data and inserting into one dump table, but would like to find a more optimized way where I find the missing tokens along with the token's present in the table.

```
SELECT MinToken + 1 Level 
 FROM (SELECT Min(Token) AS MINTOKEN,  MAX(Token) AS MAXTOKEN
         FROM dmp_SellerOrders 
        Where OrderNo = 1
          AND TradeDate = '27-Oct-20')
CONNECT BY LEVEL < MAXTOKEN - MINTOKEN
MINUS
SELECT TOKEN 
  FROM dmp_SellerOrders
 Where (OrderNo, TranserialNo) IN (SELECT OrderNo, MAX(TranserialNo) 
                                     FROM dmp_SellerOrders 
                                   GROUP BY OrderNo)
   AND TradeDate = '27-Oct-20';
```

Actual Data in Table looks like this,

```
Original Order  OrderNo TranserialNo    Token   Qty Price
                   1    1               25      100 100
                   1    1               26      100 100
                   1    1               27      100 100
                   1    1               28      100 100
                   1    1               30      100 100
                   1    1               31      100 100

Order Price Modified  OrderNo TranserialNo  Token    Qty    Price
                      1       2             25       100    200
                      1       2             26       100    200
                      1       2             27       100    200
                      1       2             28       100    200
                      1       2             30       100    200
                      1       2             31       100    200
```

I need data to show by grouping Qty, as show below,

```
OrderNo      MinToken      MaxToken      Qty  Price
1             25            28           100  200
1             29            29           0    0 
1             30            31           100  200
```

But if I group qty then I get below out,

```
OrderNo      MinToken      MaxToken      Qty  Price
1             25            31           100  200
1             29            29           0    0
```

Can any one please help me, how can I get the output as expected.

Regards,
Mehul

Comment: Please provide "real" sample data: a create table statement, insert statements for enough rows to reproduce the problem. That way we can just run reproduce your issue in our environment and give you a solution quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simplified solution without `orderNo` and `TradeDate` to demonstrate the concept.

You perform following steps in subsequent subqueries

- get all tokens and outer join to the `order` table to get a complete sequence
- find the `LAG` of the `qty` column
- set `grp_id` to 1 if there is a break. i.e. if the previos `qty` is null and the current not null or vice versa - else to 0
- cummulate the `grp_id` using analytic form of `SUM`

here the result with the sample data

```
     TOKEN        QTY      PRICE    QTY_LAG     GRP_ID CUM_GRP_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        25        100        100                     1          1
        26        100        100        100          0          1
        27        100        100        100          0          1
        28        100        100        100          0          1
        29                              100          1          2
        30        100        100                     1          3
```

The last step is a simple `GROUP BY` on `qty, price` with added cummulated group id `cum_grp_id` which splits the non adjacent groups.

Query

```
with orders as (
select 25 token, 100 qty, 100 price from dual union all
select 26 token, 100 qty, 100 price from dual union all
select 27 token, 100 qty, 100 price from dual union all
select 28 token, 100 qty, 100 price from dual union all
select 30 token, 100 qty, 100 price from dual union all
select 31 token, 100 qty, 100 price from dual),
tokens as (
select min(token) min_token, max(token) max_token from orders),
all_tokens as (
select min_token - 1 + level token from tokens
connect by level <= max_token - min_token),
grp as (
select
 t.token,
 o.qty, o.price, 
 lag(o.qty) over (order by t.token) as qty_lag
from  all_tokens t
left outer join orders o
on t.token = o.token),
grp2 as (
select 
 token, qty, price, qty_lag,
 case when qty is null and qty_lag is null or qty is not null and qty_lag is not null then 0 else 1 end as grp_id
from grp),
grp3 as (
select 
  token, qty, price, qty_lag, grp_id,
  sum(grp_id) over (order by token) cum_grp_id
from grp2)
select  min(token), max(token), qty, price
from grp3
group by cum_grp_id, qty, price
order by 1
```

result

```
MIN(TOKEN) MAX(TOKEN)        QTY      PRICE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        25         28        100        100
        29         29                      
        30         30        100        100
```

Adapt if required by partitioning the analytic function by `orderNo` and/or `tradeDate`.

Comment: But there might be many other clients where I can get such missing token in between. Though there is Min and Max values in Tokens. MinToken = 25 and MaxToken = 96.

Comment: You must first describe what do you understand under the *client* in your data and then add a `partition by` clause to the analytic functions. I can't do the *latter* before you do the *former* @Mehul

Comment: Thx for the support. I got the output for my issue.